# Optaplanner - Dynamic constraint level

Tags: optaplanner

I recently started the migration from Drools to Constraint Streams and love it so far, but I have a problem with penalizeConfigurable() and constraint configuration. The level and weight of some constraints can be changed from the UI, I used to do this with Drools :

```
rule "someConstraint"
    when
        $constraint : Constraint()
        ...
    then
        if ($constraint.level() == ConstraintLevel.HARD) {
            scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $constraint.weight());
        } else if ($constraint.level() == ConstraintLevel.MEDIUM) {
            scoreHolder.addMediumConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $constraint.weight());
        } else {
            scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, - $constraint.weight());
        }
end
```

However, I don't see how I can achieve this with penalizeConfigurable() and constraint configuration (regarding the level). In my case, it's possible to have the same type of constraint used twice or more but with a different level and weight, the only solution I can think of is to duplicate the constraint implementation and filter by level, but it feels quite dirty to do that. Any suggestions ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it ("correct" as in "as designed") is to use [Constraint Configuration](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/score-calculation/score-calculation.html#constraintConfiguration) and define your constraint weights there.

The configuration instance is stored in the planning solution. Therefore for different solutions, you store different instances of constraint configuration with different constraint weights. This allows you to score constraints dynamically, and even disable some constraints by setting their weights to zero.

At the solver config level, it could be supplemented by choosing a different constraint provided implementation for different problems, making the possibilities truly limitless.

Comment: Thank you for you quick response ! I'm using Constraint Configuration for the weight and it works well, but my problem is really about score levels. What I would like to do is to use the score level that was set by the user (keeping in mind that I can have multiple instance with different level for the same type of constraint) to change the level of the penalty. Using one of the example on github : .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, DayOnRequest::getWeight)
I would like to do this : .penalize(DayOnRequest::getLevel, DayOnRequest::getWeight)

Comment: We do not support match-based constraint weights. (That's what the match weight is for.) That said, you can configure the score level in your constraint configuration; the only thing you can not do is to set it based on what happens in the constraint.